# Matlab: data structure for storing { Key( double x, double y) : Value (z)}

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I want to create a lookup Data Map in Matlab. If I know an x and y value, it searches nearest (x,y) and takes value from the data structure.

`{ Key( double x, double y)  :  Value (z)}`

x and y coordinates are doubles, and each x y pair is mapped to a value. The x and y are not integers and not evenly spaced out. so I can not use a 3d array. Map is not a good idea, because it is a one-to-one mapping.

any suggestions?

Comment: The [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is the best data structure to find the nearest element to a spatial location. I don't know of any MATLAB implementations, but I suggest you search the [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), likely someone has implemented it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scatteredInterpolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html). Using the example that is included in @LuisMendo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845126/6579744):

```
dataxy = [ 1    2  
           1.5  1.1
           3.2  1.9
          -0.3 -3.4
           4.2  2.1];
dataz = [ 10
          90
          40
         -60
          50];

xy =   [2.4   3;
        6.5   1.8];

F =  scatteredInterpolant(dataxy, dataz, 'nearest');

result = F(xy);
```

Here `F` can be regarded as a lookup data map.

Comment: Thank you so much! is it possible to store (z1, z2) as a pair in dataz?

Comment: I think it is : `dataz = [z1 z2];F = scatteredinterpolant(dataxy, 1:size(dataz,1), 'nearest'); result = dataz(F(xy),:);`

Answer (score 2):

*This is a manual approach. It is probably better to use [@rahnema1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846751/2586922).*

You can use a three-column matrix, `data`, where the columns represent *x*, *y*, *z* respectively. Then given a two-column input `xy`, where the columns represent *x*, *y*, searching for the nearest points in `data` can be done by

1. Computing a matrix `dist` with all distances between `data` and `xy`. The simplest way is using [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) from the Statistics Toolbox, which allows you to specify Euclidean or any other desired distance. Or it can be done manually; see below.
2. Obtaining the arg min of the distances from each point in `xy` to all points in `data`. This is given by the second output of [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html).
3. Use that to index into the `data` matrix.

```
data = [ 1    2    10;
         1.5  1.1  90;
         3.2  1.9  40;
        -0.3 -3.4 -60;
         4.2  2.1  50];
xy =   [2.4   3;
        6.5   1.8];
dist = pdist2(data(:,[1 2]), xy, 'euclidean');
[~, ind] = min(dist, [], 1);
result = data(ind,3);
```

gives

```
result =
    40
    50
```

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, the squared Euclidean distances can be computed manually using [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) or [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
dist = sum((permute(data(:,[1 2]), [1 3 2])-permute(xy, [3 1 2])).^2, 3);
```

or

```
dist = sum((bsxfun(@minus, permute(data(:,[1 2]), [1 3 2]), permute(xy, [3 1 2]))).^2, 3);
```